# System.data.entity.validation.DbEntityValdationException Error Come when save the data

Tags: asp.net-mvc

This my Controller

```
public JsonResult SaveBillingSystemParameters(BillingSystemParameters model)
        {
            var id = -1;
            //Initialize the newId variable 
            var userId = Helpers.GetLoggedInUserId();
            var currentDate = Helpers.GetInvariantCultureDateTime();
            var defaultCorporateId = Helpers.GetSysAdminCorporateID();

            //Check if Model is not null
            if (model != null)
            {
                using (var bal = new BillingSystemParametersBal())
                {
                    model.CorporateId = defaultCorporateId;
                    if (model.Id > 0)
                    {
                        model.ModifiedBy = userId;
                        model.ModifiedDate = currentDate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model.CreatedBy = userId;
                        model.CreatedDate = currentDate;
                        model.CorporateId = Helpers.GetSysAdminCorporateID();
                    }

                    //Call the AddBillingSystemParameters Method to Add / Update current BillingSystemParameters
                    id = bal.SaveBillingSystemParameters(model);
                }
            }
            return Json(id);
        }

//Bal class

public int SaveBillingSystemParameters(BillingSystemParameters model)
        {
            using (var rep = UnitOfWork.BillingSystemParametersRepository)
            {
                if (model.Id > 0)
                {
                    var current = rep.GetSingle(model.Id);
                    model.CreatedBy = current.CreatedBy;
                    model.CreatedDate = current.CreatedDate;
                    rep.UpdateEntity(model, model.Id);
                }
                else
                    rep.Create(model);

                return model.Id;
            }
        }
```

I am getting following error
[image]

Answer (score 0):

do what exception message says, inspect EntityValidationErrror
this exception usually means you're trying to break some constraint like varchar filed width
if you browse through this param you'll get more details on type of constrain SaveChanges() tried to brake